# Give a value to (a constructor-type function that only takes a reference)

Tags: rust

Suppose there is a function

```
fn basket_from_apple(apple: &'a mut Apple) -> Basket<'a>;
```

which makes a Basket which refers to Apple somewhere inside of it. I can't modify the code for basket_from_apple. It's in a different package.

I want to be able to just give basket_from_apple the Apple, so I don't need to hold on to it, and I want Basket's Drop to destroy the Apple along with the Basket.

Is there some way of doing that in rust? For instance, is there some kind of box-like object, AppleBasket, that I could somehow put the Apple and the Basket into? I want to keep the Apple private, and I want to keep the Basket unmovable, but still accessible by immutable reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your `AppleBasket` using the [`ouroboros`](https://docs.rs/ouroboros/latest/ouroboros/) library, which allows creating “self-referential structs” that contain parts that borrow from other parts. Here is what that looks like:

```rust
#[ouroboros::self_referencing]
struct AppleBasket {
    apple: Apple,
    #[borrows(mut apple)]
    #[covariant]
    basket: Basket<'this>,
}
impl AppleBasket {
    fn from_apple(a: Apple) -> AppleBasket {
        AppleBasket::new(a, |a: &mut Apple| basket_from_apple(a))
    }
}
// ...
fn some_func() {
    let a = Apple::new();
    let ab = AppleBasket::from_apple(a);
    // `ab` can be freely moved
    let b = ab.borrow_basket();
}
```

Sometimes, this is the best, or only, way to solve problems such as you describe. However, `ouroboros` has some performance costs, risk of unsoundness (if there are any bugs), and a somewhat necessarily-awkward API, so you should see it as the last resort; often there is a way to avoid needing the borrow, and put types together in a different way.

- The very basic case is that maybe you don't actually need to keep the `Basket` around, but can write a function that creates it every time it's needed.
- Sometimes libraries are simply poorly designed — the author did not think of supporting use cases where it would be useful to keep the `Basket` around, but there are such, and the best solution is to modify the library (and contribute the improvement back if it's welcome). (For example, maybe the `Basket` can hold a value of a generic type that implements `AsMut<Apple>`, or a custom `Fruit` trait).

  (But there can also be reasons, obvious or subtle, why libraries' types *must* work the way they do.)
- You can put the `Apple` and `Basket` in local variables in a loop running on a thread or `async` task, which accepts messages instructing it on how to manipulate the `Basket`. The message channel (in a suitable wrapper type, perhaps) can be passed around freely.
- If there's only ever one `Apple` (or a finite number) then you can [`Box::leak()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak) it so as to get an `&'static mut Apple`, allowing you to create a `Basket<'static>`. The disadvantage of this is that it's not (safely) possible to recover the memory used by the `Apple`s, so it should not be done if apples are regularly created and destroyed.